# Using Elderberries in Cooking

Tags: fruit, elderberries

I noticed that there's lots of elderberries near where I live, and I had an idea about making an elderberry brulee, but I'm sure that the elderberries would be a little too sharp if simply cooked.

Would it be worth cooking them down with sugar first, then maybe removing the skins with a sieve? Any thoughts welcome on this.

Comment: Your mother was a hamster...

Comment: Argh! I had refrained from making that joke! I shall now have to taunt you.

Answer (score 2):

One of the very English methods for rhubarb cake is to cook the rhubarb in apple juice first.
Since rhubarb is incredibly tart, the cooking and the apple juice help relax it a little.

The same should work for you with the elderberries. Naturally, you can substitute a sugar solution for the apple juice, but you should dissolve the sugar in the water first and then add the berries.

Comment: eh, it really doesn't matter. you can bung all the ingredients in the pan at the same time. or not, as you choose, but there's no real difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to get them and try it yourself. Sugar is cheap, cooking them down won't take long. It's always better to experiment and see what you like; this will make you a better cook over time.